# Gaps in shadows even with zero bias set Unity

Tags: unity, lighting, shadows

I have a problem with gaps in shadows in Unity. I know that there are many questions about that, but all of the answers are usually about setting bias property to 0. But this didn't help me. I use Point light on my scene with the settings:
[image]
And even when I put two scaled Cubes to the scene, I get the result like this (a quite big
shadow gap between green and gray plates):
[image]
Is there a property I also need to change so I can get normal shadows?

Comment: Are you editing the bias for the correct light source? Your first screenshot shows you editing a Point light source, but the second screenshot looks more like it's illuminated by a Directional light source.

Comment: I know that it looks like Directional light, but it is Point light. This boxes are quite far away from the light, so the shadows are like that